# Vector bundle and principal bundle

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Why fiber of $(P\times V)/G\rightarrow P/G$ isomorphic to $V$ ?

I think the fiber should be $V/G$, but it is not isomorphic to $V$

Picture below is from the 66 page of   Jost's Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: From which book, you are reading ?

Comment: The fiber can't be V/G because that has the wrong dimension

Comment: @Sri I have add it in my question.

Comment: @user384359  Could you detail explain it ?

Comment: @lanse7pty Roughly speaking the dimension of V/G should be dim V - dim G and the dimension of your fiber should be dim (P x V)/G - dim P/G. What is left over is dim V and not dim V/G.

Comment: @user384359  Whether the $(P\times V)/G =(P\times V)/ \sim $  ?  ($(p,v)\sim (p,v)g~~~\forall g\in G$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix a point $x$ in the base. Then the fiber over $x$ consists of the orbits of all pairs $(p,v)\in P\times V$ such that $p$ lies in the fiber over $x$. Now fix a point $p_0$ in that fiber and consider the map from $V$ to the fiber of $P\times_GV$ over $x$ which sends $v$ to the orbit of $(p_0,v)$. This is injective since $p_0\cdot g=p_0$ implies $g=e$, so $(p_0,v)$ and $(p_0,w)$ lying in the same orbit implies $v=w$. On the other hand, for each $p$ in the fiber, there is an element $g\in G$ such that $p=p_0\cdot g$. Hence the orbit of $(p,v)$ contains $(p_0,g\cdot v)$ which implies surjectivity.

Comment: Thanks . I think your proof has proved that there is a bijective between $V$ and fiber of $P\times_GV$ .  But how to understand it is isomorphic ? In fact ,I can't feel that the fiber of $P\times_GV$ is a vector space.

Comment: The vector space structure is defined via this bijection (and one shows that it is independent of the choice of $p_0$ since $G$ acts on $V$ by linear maps), so it becomes a linear isomorphism.