# Why the structure group of principal $G$-bundle must be subgroup of $G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, principal-bundles

As picture below, seemly, it is said that the structure group of principal $G$-bundle must be subgroup of $G$. Why ?

Picture below is from the 65 page of Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* .

> [image]

Comment: By definition, the transition maps take their values in $G$. If the values of those maps do not reach every values of $G$, but are rather contained in some subgroup $H\subseteq G$, then we say that $H$ is the structure group of the principal bundle. Thus, it is a subgroup of $G$ by definition.

Comment: @Spenser   I write an answer according to my understand in below. Is it right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector bundle and principal bundle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994121/vector-bundle-and-principal-bundle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosider two locally trivial 
$$
\varphi_{_U} :\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G   \\
\varphi_{_V} :\pi^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V\times G  
$$
So, 
$$
\varphi_{_V} \circ \varphi^{-1}_{_U} (x,g) \rightarrow (x,\varphi_{_{VU}}(x)g)
$$
because $\varphi_{_{VU}}(x)g\in G$, assume $\varphi_{_{VU}}(x)g=h$ , then  $\varphi_{_{VU}}(x)=hg^{-1}\in G$ . So, the structure group is subgroup of $G$.